# OpenCV - Remove small, unwanted dots/noise in an image

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, opencv3.0

I'm working in my thesis to build a music scores (sheets) recognition system. This is my input file:
[image]

This is the result after some preprocessing and staff lines removal:
[image]
The problem that I'm encounter here is that there are some super small, unwanted "dots" appeared after the staff line removal step. These dots/noise are different from the actual musical "dots" symbols: The noise dots are much smaller and they mostly appear on the staff lines. These dots/noise will affect the recognition stage later in the program.
How can I remove these dots/noise ?

Comment: Can you share the code which you used to generate the output. Maybe some change in your variables would result in better outputs.

Comment: I would suggest applying Sauvola's threshold algorithm on your original image followed by a suitable morphological operation as mentioned in the answers

Comment: In order to remove small dots (spurious noise), you could try applying a median filter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If there are very small dots, you might want to try some simple image processing techniques like [erosion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erosion_(morphology)), they work on binary images. It is a standard function available in matlab/openCV. You just need to define the size of your kernel (which is the size of dots you need to ignore).

Answer (score 1):

You have two simple solutions:

- A geodesic opening <=> an erosion followed by a geodesic reconstruction. If it is not implemented in OpenCV, you can perform a simple opening (erosion + dilation). The geodesic opening has the advantage to remove the small patterns, but to keep the original shape of the remaining patterns.
- Apply a threshold to find the dark patterns, label them, and delete the smallest ones. This result is comparable to my previous suggestion, the difference is that you don't use a structuring element.